# How can I efficiently parse a large array and distribute the corresponding entries among a set of subroutines in Fortran?

Tags: arrays, fortran, gfortran

I have a fortran subroutine that receives a large array of unsorted items and needs to call other subroutines that are responsible for parsing and storing each item depending on its (discrete) type.
I created an example that emulates what I am trying to do:

```
module animal_farm

  type :: Animal
    character(256) :: animal_type
    integer :: age
  end type Animal

  type :: Rabbit
    integer :: age, estimated_carrots_eaten
  end type Rabbit

  type(Rabbit), dimension(:), allocatable :: rabbit_params
  contains
  subroutine parse_animals(large_animal_list)
    type(Animal), dimension(:), intent(in) :: large_animal_list
    integer :: i

    do i = 1, size(large_animal_list)
      select case(large_animal_list(i)%animal_type)
        case('rabbit')
          call parse_rabbit_information(large_animal_list(i),i,size(large_animal_list))
        case('horse')
          ! call parse_horse_information(large_animal_list(i),i,size(large_animal_list))
          continue
        case('bird')
          ! call parse_bird_information(large_animal_list(i),i,size(large_animal_list))
          continue
        case('dog')
          ! call parse_dog_information(large_animal_list(i),i,size(large_animal_list))
          continue
      end select
    end do
  end subroutine parse_animals

subroutine parse_rabbit_information(rabbit_entry, animal_list_index, animal_list_size)
  type(Animal), intent(in) :: rabbit_entry
  integer, intent(in) :: animal_list_index, animal_list_size

  if (.not. allocated(rabbit_params)) allocate(rabbit_params(animal_list_size))
  rabbit_params(animal_list_index)%age = rabbit_entry%age
  rabbit_params(animal_list_index)%estimated_carrots_eaten = rabbit_entry%age*10*365
end subroutine parse_rabbit_information

subroutine feed_rabbit(animal_list_index)
  integer, intent(in) :: animal_list_index
  rabbit_params(animal_list_index)%estimated_carrots_eaten = rabbit_params(animal_list_index)%estimated_carrots_eaten+1
end subroutine feed_rabbit

end module animal_farm

Program TEST

    use animal_farm

    type(Animal), dimension(10) :: my_animal_list

    my_animal_list(1)%animal_type = "rabbit"
    my_animal_list(1)%age = 5
    my_animal_list(2)%animal_type = "dog"
    my_animal_list(2)%age = 6
    my_animal_list(3)%animal_type = "horse"
    my_animal_list(3)%age = 1
    my_animal_list(4)%animal_type = "rabbit"
    my_animal_list(4)%age = 3
    my_animal_list(5)%animal_type = "bird"
    my_animal_list(5)%age = 4
    my_animal_list(6)%animal_type = "horse"
    my_animal_list(6)%age = 6
    my_animal_list(7)%animal_type = "rabbit"
    my_animal_list(7)%age = 2
    my_animal_list(8)%animal_type = "rabbit"
    my_animal_list(8)%age = 2
    my_animal_list(9)%animal_type = "dog"
    my_animal_list(9)%age = 4
    my_animal_list(10)%animal_type = "horse"
    my_animal_list(10)%age = 7
    call parse_animals(my_animal_list)
    call feed_rabbit(1)
    call feed_rabbit(4)
End Program TEST
```

I am currently creating a datastructure of the same size as the `large_animal_list` array for each defined animal. Later on, I want to be able to use functions in the submodules that are given an index value from `large_animal_list` and perform some kind of computation based on the corresponding entry in this submodule.
So if `large_animal_list` is 1000 items long and an item of `animal_type=rabbit` is at index 250, I want to have a function in the submodule `rabbit_parser` that receives the value `250` and performs a certain action with the animal in the `rabbit_list` datastructure.

The downsides I see with this approach are that I need to allocate an array that is only partially filled with values in the submodules. I also have to perform an `if (.not. allocated(rabbit_list))` test every time one of the `parse_*_information` subroutines is called, which can be performance intensive if a particular submodule needs to allocate multiple arrays of length `size(large_animal_list)` upon initialization.

I was also thinking about an approach where I would first count the number of occurrences of each `animal_type` and pass a new array that only contains the entries that correspond to the particular submodule, or make use of some sort of linked list structure. This requires the definition of a mapping array that maps the index of an animal in `large_animal_list` to its local index, e.g. in `rabbit_list` in `rabbit_parser` while also making the `parse_animal` significantly more complicated.

What is the best way to improve the current approach to make the entire program more resource efficient?

EDIT: I also created a [followup post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883602/how-can-a-fortran-program-that-iterates-over-an-array-and-distributes-the-corres) to this post.

Comment: Can you tidy up your code, it's quite confusing?  For example one of the subroutines calls another subroutine called `rabbit_parser` but that's the name of a module, which contains a subroutine called `parse_rabbit_information`.  Then you have an array called `rabbit_list` which is not declared to be `allocatable` but which is the 'subject' of an `allocate` statement.  And, fear not, this is the last time I'll comment on your code or questions.  If I can't answer your question after your next set of edits (should you make any) I'll keep quiet.

Comment: If what worries you is the waste of ressource because of partially filled arrays, then arrays of indexes to map a global entry to the local entries is an obvious solution. And no, it's not complicated :). The global index could even be a component of your `type :: Animal`. Besides, there are name mistakes and undeclared variable in the code in your question.

Comment: @PierU I see, I will try to implement my implementation of this solution with my abovementioned example and make a new post tomorrow that I actually tested, unfortunately I didn't have the time to compile the example I wrote today. There are a few more points aside from the mapping that might be considered overhead that I already touched on in my last post, like the use of ids as array indeces etc., I will make sure it will actually run this time.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I will try to improve the quality of my posts in the future, thank you for the feedback