# How can a Fortran program that iterates over an array and distributes the corresponding entries among a set of subroutines be designed efficiently?

Tags: arrays, design-patterns, fortran, gfortran

I have a fortran subroutine that receives a large unsorted array of a certain type and needs to call other subroutines that are responsible for parsing and storing each item depending on one of the values declared inside of it.

In my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73857650/how-can-i-efficiently-parse-a-large-array-and-distribute-the-corresponding-entri), I shared a program that does just that but had a few design flaws, like allocating a large array for every type that needs to be parsed and only filling out the required values, or calling `if (.not. allocated())` multiple times for every array element.

I have created another version of this program that addresses these downsides, but entails some other design paradigm issues that need to be improved upon:

```
module animal_farm

  integer :: &
    RABBIT_ID = 1, &
    DOG_ID= 2, &
    BIRD_ID= 3, &
    HORSE_ID= 4, &
    current_animal_id

  type :: Animal
    character(256) :: animal_type
    integer :: &
      age
  end type Animal

  type(Animal), dimension(:), allocatable, target :: & ! temporary arrays storing all the entries from large_animal_list for each animal
    rabbit_entries, &
    horse_entries, &
    bird_entries, &
    dog_entries

  type(Animal), dimension(:), pointer :: &
    current_animal_list

  integer, dimension(:), allocatable  :: animal_list_mapping

  ! this type and array is defined for every available animal, but only Rabbit is defined here to keep this example as simple as possible
  type :: Rabbit
    integer :: &
    age, &
    estimated_carrots_eaten ! parameters like this are defined differently for each animal, requiring a new *_params array for each type
  end type Rabbit
  type(Rabbit), dimension(:), allocatable :: & ! list of rabbit entries alongside parameters calculated specifically for rabbits
    rabbit_params

  integer, dimension(4) :: & ! number of available animals is 4
    animal_ids, &
    animal_counts, & ! temporary array to count the number of animals in large_animal_list
    individual_animal_indeces ! temporary array that stores the current index of one of the animal specific lists

  contains

subroutine parse_animals(large_animal_list)
  type(Animal), dimension(:), intent(in) :: large_animal_list
  integer :: i

  allocate(animal_list_mapping(size(large_animal_list)))

  animal_counts = 0
  do i = 1, size(large_animal_list)
    select case(large_animal_list(i)%animal_type)
      case('rabbit')
        current_animal_id = RABBIT_ID
      case('horse')
        current_animal_id = HORSE_ID
      case('bird')
        current_animal_id = BIRD_ID
      case('dog')
        current_animal_id = DOG_ID
    end select
    animal_counts(current_animal_id) = animal_counts(current_animal_id)+1
  end do

  allocate(rabbit_entries(animal_counts(RABBIT_ID)))
  allocate(horse_entries(animal_counts(HORSE_ID)))
  allocate(bird_entries(animal_counts(BIRD_ID)))
  allocate(dog_entries(animal_counts(DOG_ID)))

  individual_animal_indeces = 1
  do i = 1, size(large_animal_list)
    select case(large_animal_list(i)%animal_type)
      case('rabbit')
        current_animal_id = RABBIT_ID
        current_animal_list => rabbit_entries
      case('horse')
        current_animal_id = HORSE_ID
        current_animal_list => horse_entries
      case('bird')
        current_animal_id = BIRD_ID
        current_animal_list => bird_entries
      case('dog')
        current_animal_id = DOG_ID
        current_animal_list => dog_entries
    end select
    current_animal_list(individual_animal_indeces(current_animal_id))%age = large_animal_list(i)%age
    animal_list_mapping(i) = individual_animal_indeces(current_animal_id)
    individual_animal_indeces(current_animal_id) = animal_counts(current_animal_id)+1
  end do

  if (animal_counts(RABBIT_ID)>0) call parse_rabbit_information(rabbit_entries)
  ! if (animal_counts(HORSE_ID)>0) call parse_horse_information(horse_entries)
  ! if (animal_counts(BIRD_ID)>0) call parse_bird_information(bird_entries)
  ! if (animal_counts(DOG_ID)>0) call parse_dog_information(dog_entries)

end subroutine parse_animals


subroutine parse_rabbit_information(rabbit_entries)
  type(Animal), dimension(:), intent(in) :: rabbit_entries
  integer :: i

  allocate(rabbit_params(size(rabbit_entries)))
  do i=1, size(rabbit_entries)

    rabbit_params(i)%age = rabbit_entries(i)%age
    rabbit_params(i)%estimated_carrots_eaten = rabbit_entries(i)%age*10*365
  end do
end subroutine parse_rabbit_information

subroutine feed_rabbit(animal_list_index)
  integer, intent(in) :: animal_list_index
  integer :: rabbit_params_index

  rabbit_params_index = animal_list_mapping(animal_list_index)
  rabbit_params(rabbit_params_index)%estimated_carrots_eaten = rabbit_params(rabbit_params_index)%estimated_carrots_eaten+1
end subroutine feed_rabbit

end module animal_farm

Program TEST

    use animal_farm

    type(Animal), dimension(10) :: my_animal_list

    my_animal_list(1)%animal_type = "rabbit"
    my_animal_list(1)%age = 5
    my_animal_list(2)%animal_type = "dog"
    my_animal_list(2)%age = 6
    my_animal_list(3)%animal_type = "horse"
    my_animal_list(3)%age = 1
    my_animal_list(4)%animal_type = "rabbit"
    my_animal_list(4)%age = 3
    my_animal_list(5)%animal_type = "bird"
    my_animal_list(5)%age = 4
    my_animal_list(6)%animal_type = "horse"
    my_animal_list(6)%age = 6
    my_animal_list(7)%animal_type = "rabbit"
    my_animal_list(7)%age = 2
    my_animal_list(8)%animal_type = "rabbit"
    my_animal_list(8)%age = 2
    my_animal_list(9)%animal_type = "dog"
    my_animal_list(9)%age = 4
    my_animal_list(10)%animal_type = "horse"
    my_animal_list(10)%age = 7
    call parse_animals(my_animal_list)
    call feed_rabbit(1)
    call feed_rabbit(4)
End Program TEST
```

This version only calls each subroutine responsible for handling the different item types once, and passes an array that already has the correct size and can simply be allocated in the target subroutine. If possible, I would like to improve the following points:

1. The current solution involves the use of two loops, the first one where the number of occurrences for each item type is counted, and another where the now allocated arrays that are being passed to the subroutines are filled with the corresponding values. This requires the use of helper arrays such as `animal_counts` or `individual_animal_indeces`, which in turn also need to know how many different types of animals they need to account for (hardcoded to be 4 in the example). I also tried using some sort of linked-list structure to improve this, which allowed me to only use one loop, but the values corresponding to each type still need to be stored in an array of the correct size.
2. To address the issues from point 1., I thought about placing the defined `*_ID` variables in an array, so the helper arrays can be defined with `integer, dimension(size(animal_id_array))`. The defined `*_ID` variables are also being used as array indeces, which requires them to be defined by hand from 1-x. It is not very clean to have to add and remove ids from a list like this and redefine the array where they are stored, every time an id is added or removed. The generation of ids can be achieved with the `enum, bind(c); enumerator` operator, but to get to the number of ids you still need to create a separate array or hardcode the amount somewhere.

How can this program be modified to improve its performance and memory-efficiency without making it needlessly difficult to read and maintain?

Comment: Haven't read all the code, but to count the number of animals of each species: `do i=1,4; animal_counts(i) = count(large_animal_list(:)%animal_type == i); enddo`

Answer (score 4):

> How can this program be modified to improve its performance and memory-efficiency without making it needlessly difficult to read and maintain?

Working towards all three of these goals at once is almost always difficult, and sometimes outright impossible. Unless you have specific reasons to do otherwise, I would recommend first focussing on making your code easy to read and maintain, and only then trying to improve its performance and memory-efficiency. The latter step should only be done after profiling your code to see which bits actually need optimising.

With that in mind, let's see if we can simplify your code a bit. Since you already have a number of types, let's go full object-oriented, and introduce some polymorphism.

If we're inheriting `Rabbit` from `Animal`, we can avoid storing the `animal_type` field, and instead generate it using a type-bound procedure, something like

```
module animal_mod
  implicit none
  
  ! Define the base Animal type.
  type, abstract :: Animal
    integer :: age
  contains
    procedure(animal_type_Animal), deferred, nopass :: animal_type
  end type

  ! Define the interface for the `animal_type` functions.
  interface
    function animal_type_Animal() result(output)
      character(256) :: output
    end function
  end interface
end animal_mod
```

and

```
module rabbit_mod
  use animal_mod
  implicit none
  
  ! Define the `Rabbit` type as an extension of the `Animal` type.
  ! Note that `Rabbit` has an `age` because it is an `Animal`.
  type, extends(Animal) :: Rabbit
    integer :: estimated_carrots_eaten
  contains
    procedure, nopass :: animal_type => animal_type_Rabbit
  end type

contains

  ! Define the implementation of `animal_type` for the `Rabbit` type.
  function animal_type_Rabbit() result(output)
    character(256) :: output
    output = "rabbit"
  end function
end module
```

Now we want to be able to create an array of animals. Fortran doesn't allow polymorphic arrays, so we need to define a type which contains an animal and which can be made into an array. Something like

```
module animal_box_mod
  use animal_mod
  implicit none
  
  type :: AnimalBox
    class(Animal), allocatable :: a
  end type
end module
```

We can now create an array of animals, e.g.

```
type(AnimalBox) :: animals(3)

animals(1)%a = Rabbit(age=3, estimated_carrots_eaten=0)
animals(2)%a = Frog(age=3, estimated_bugs_eaten=4, length=1.7786)
animals(3)%a = Mouse(age=4, estimated_cheese_eaten=7, coat="Yellow")
```

Instead of using a method like `feed_rabbit(7)`, you can instead use a type-bound method. If we add this as

```
module rabbit_module
  type, extends(Animal) :: Rabbit
    ... ! as above
  contains
    ... ! as above
    procedure :: feed
  end type
contains
  ... ! as above
  subroutine feed(this)
    class(Rabbit), intent(inout) :: this
    this%estimated_carrots_eaten = this%estimated_carrots_eaten + 1
  end subroutine
end module
```

then we can call this using our `animals` array as

```
select type(a => animals(1)%a); type is(Rabbit)
  a.feed()
end select
```